# How to unzip a json file with password in swift?

Tags: ios, json, swift, zip

## Solution:

To he who got this error:

> [SSZipArchive] Failed to open file on unzipping.(Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=20 "Not a directory")

Make sure the destination is a **directory** when using the unzipFile function.

```swift
SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: String, toDestination: String, overwrite: Bool, password: String?)
```

## Question:

How to unzip the json file with password in Swift?
I used third-party SDK and downloaded a file, and the file type is `Data`.

The file is announced to be a zip file, and need to be decompressed to a `json` file with **password**.

I save the file to `FileManager.documentDirectory` and name it with `.zip` extension.
Then I tried to unzip the file with `ZipArchive`, but I got the following error:

```
[SSZipArchive] Failed to open file on unzipping.(Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=20 "Not a directory")
```

I also saved the file with `.json` extension then unzipped it, but got the same error as above.

I downloaded the saved file in container and opened it, and the results are listed as below:

(1) To a `.zip` file:
I couldn't open it.

```
Can't decompressed xxx.json.zip to Documents.
(error -2: No similar file or directory)
```

(2) To a `.json` file:
I got some garbled text like

```
∫ôFk;|T|D˚®è•Éjê‹¡Ò;X≈∞)˘–7ÑØZl≥MÇz-n·ù!ê}˜fﬂêÔæv\£F>RBZ1Myfª—Q˘∏àúˇá≥˙Ïèãd”
```

Here shows my code.

```swift
func saveZipFile(filename: String, file: Data) {
    let documentDirURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileURL = documentDirURL.appendingPathComponent("\(filename).zip")
    print("File Path: \(fileURL.path)")

    do {
        try file.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)

        try SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: fileURL.path, toDestination: fileURL.path, overwrite: true, password: finalKey)
    } catch let err {
        print("Error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

The file should be a human readable json file if decompressed correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
func saveZipFile(filename: String, file: Data) {

    let documentDirURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first!
    let fileURL = documentDirURL.appendingPathComponent("\(filename).zip")
    let destination = documentDirURL.path + "/MyZipFiles"
    print("File Path: \(fileURL.path)")

    do {
        try file.write(to: fileURL, options: .atomic)

        try SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: fileURL.path, toDestination: destination, overwrite: true, password: finalKey)
    } catch let err {
        print("Error: \(err.localizedDescription)")
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for your reply. I find that the destination of  ```unzipFile``` function should be a directory, and which is exactly what error hint for.

Comment: If my answer helped you, then please don't forget to vote it up. Cheers !